# Linux tr command failing "misaligned construct"

Tags: linux

Linux tr command failing "misaligned construct".

This code was working fine, but started failing recently.

also we see , string Y is there. Don't know where this coming from.

Code:

```
if [ "${V_INSTANCE_CODE}" = "" ];
then
    V_INSTANCE_CODE="A1"
fi
V_INSTANCE_CODE_LWR=`echo ${V_INSTANCE_CODE} | tr [[:upper:]] [[:lower:]]`
```

Error Sysout log:

```
+ V_INSTANCE_CODE=''
+ [ '' '=' '' ]
+ V_INSTANCE_CODE=A1
+ echo A1
+ tr Y '[[:lower:]]'
tr: misaligned [:upper:] and/or [:lower:] construct
+ V_INSTANCE_CODE_LWR=''
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]'
```

Comment: You have a file Y and [[:upper:]] change to Y in your script.
You need use quotes!
You can check run 
echo [[:upper:]]
Result: Y

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @Šerg thanks a lot.. There was a file named Y.. After removing it worked.